# Loading Android Fragment on second time

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

There is a problem with loading view on second time. First time there is no problem, and my fragment is properly loading, but on second time there is i don't know default view or empty. Here is my essential code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact, container, false);

Context context = getActivity();

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragments = new Vector<android.support.v4.app.Fragment>();
fragments.add(android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(context, Fragment1.class.getName()));
fragments.add(android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(context, Fragment2.class.getName()));
fragments.add(android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(context, Fragment3.class.getName()));
mPagerAdapter =new PagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

return rootView;
```

From MainActivity:

```
if (fragment != null) {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
    setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

Comment: post fragment initializing code. second time means selection from drawer list ?

Comment: yes navigation is based on drawer list